# Standard Java Project Description Format

Tags: java

I'm coming from the .NET world where Visual Studio is pretty ubiquitous. VS has a .sln file which pretty exhaustively describes a project, including where to find source files, dependencies, etc.

Now I'm doing some java coding in a team. My problem is this: I'm using intellij and others are using eclipse (while others could be using some other IDE). Is there a standard project description file that can be shared among IDE's? I obviously don't want to put my intellij specific files to source control. So what I'm looking for is a standard that pretty much any self-respecting IDE would recognize which you could point it to and it would be able to interpret the project structure, how to find dependencies, the class paths, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note quite. But you have a "way out". You can use [Maven2](http://maven.apache.org/). It has a unified `pom` file which contains all:

- source folders (note: maven imposes a default convention on those, but they are still configurable)
- compiler level
- dependencies
- build steps
- etc..

(Of course that would require to install the maven plugins for both IDEs)

Another option would be to force either of the IDEs and commit their proprietary descriptors.

Answer (score 3):

Maven should be able to do it (a project build manager and source control overlay), but alas, there is no standard project file. There are Maven plug-ins available for all the major IDEs. http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: Yeah, I'm using maven2 at the moment and I guess it is the best of the options. I guess I was hoping there was something a little more lightweight than maven which focused solely on this task. Oh well :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have posted, Ant and Maven are pretty much the de facto project spec utilities in the Java world.  Those are both generally easy to learn -- a fair learning curve, but nothing dramatic -- and are pretty powerful.  You could speak to your team members or leader and see how they've dealt with it -- I'm sure it isn't a new problem.

Aside from that, a lot of development teams (in my experience, at least) try to avoid putting project files in source control.  The developers are required to basically create their own projects in whatever IDE they're using.  It makes getting started on a project a little more difficult for a developer coming fresh into an existing project, but it also helps the developer get a little better acquainted with the project.

At my shop (very, *very* small team), we use Eclipse, but we still have to manage the workspaces (similar to VS solutions, but not quite the same) ourselves.  I've created some Ant scripts for use on our continuous integration server, and that won't necessarily keep problems from arising, but it helps make them more obvious when they do.

Comment: Maven can generate IDE project files - `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and `mvn idea:idea`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such standard project description file as far as I know. But intellij is able to take an eclipse and convert to an intellij project. Also you could look at [maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

There is not one.  You could switch to an build system using [ANT](http://ant.apache.org/) (similar to Make) but that has pitfalls of it's own.  You will get the most mileage if you and your team standardize on an IDE though ...

Comment: Ant doesn't demonstrate to the IDE how the project is set up, so it wouldn't automatically find the source files, output dir, dependencies, etc. This is what the poster requires. but the IDE argument is completely valid -- standardisation is key :) But some tools are more powerful for some stuff than others.

Comment: @Chris No, but it does cross IDE's.   I didn't say it was the answer, but a possible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want here is for a developer using Eclipse to edit the project settings and have those changes reflected in IDEA for some other developer.   If that's the case, then  [Maven](http://maven.apache.org) is what you want.  IDEA 9.x has great support for Maven, and so does Eclipse.   If a developer that uses Eclipse edits the dependencies in the Maven project files (pom.xml files), then IDEA can import the files and change it's project settings.

RE: ANT vs Maven - In this respect (syncing project settings) ANT build files won't work because they are imperative (script-like) rather than declarative.

Answer (score 0):

Maven should be the preferred way but most IDE's now days support some kind of ant based project which is what most of the IDES use internally. Usually called free-form projects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Maven fan myself.  I'd recommend Ant long before Maven.

If you're using IntelliJ, I'd argue that it does have a pretty standard idiom.  And since it can import any Eclipse project file, you'll be on safe turf laying things out as IntelliJ does it.

I don't check in my IntelliJ project files, but the /src, /lib, /test, /resources etc. are all fair game.

The true answer should be that your team should huddle up and come up with a standard layout that you agree on regardless of IDE.  You've got to check code into SVN sometime.

Your question is interesting to me, because I'm trying to go in the other direction (Java->C#, IntelliJ->Visual Studio), and I'm having trouble doing the mapping in the other direction.

I think it's just part of learning a language and its native IDE.  I find that it's best to find an experienced guide.

One problem you'll have is that the .NET universe is isotropic (all things Microsoft), where even your small corner of the Java universe is heterogeneous (IntelliJ and Eclipse and NetBeans).  You're less likely to find one true answer for all of Java.